# List all content by post type

Tags: plugin-development

I am writing a plugin in which I need to list post/page/attachment by each type.

First I get all post type:

```
$post_types = get_post_types (array('public'=>true));
```

Then I create a loop and query posts for each post type, and print out:

```
foreach ($post_types as $type_name => $post_type) : 
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => null, // any parent
        );          
    $posts = get_pages($args);      
    if ($posts):            
            foreach ($posts as $post) :
        print_r($post);             
        endforeach;
    endif;
endforeach;
```

However, on plugin page, I don't see anything print out.

Could anyone please give a hint?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `get_pages()` is deprecated... use `get_posts()` or `new WP_Query()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `get_pages` use

```
new WP_Query($args)
```

It will get all the posts/pages/attachments

Comment: Hi Kuljeet, WP_Query works for me. Thanks alot. I am sorry that I don't have enough reputation to vote your answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Use $post_types = query_posts('post_type'=>'post/page'); for specific post types.

Comment: `query_posts()` should never be used, _and_ your code cannot work. Also, an explanation would be useful.

Comment: I have found query_posts() more useful and faster then WP_Query();. I don't know why you are telling it shouldn't be used. If i use like example of "Portfolio" type custom posts. Then it should be like this $post_type= query_posts(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'posts_per_page' => -1));

Comment: It [ruins the main query and pagination](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts), it cannot be faster than `WP_Query`, because it is a wrapper for that.

Comment: Forgot to say in the end of query it needs to reset the query. wp_reset_query(); Please see the reference for better understand. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Comment: I know that function in and out. Plugins hooking in _during_ an active `query_posts()` get still the wrong information. Always use `WP_Query` or a filter on `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: I have found the best query is get_posts() http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts